# What is the danger of side effects in Java 8 Streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to understand warnings I found in the Documentation on Streams. I've gotten in the habit of using forEach() as a general purpose iterator. And that's lead me to writing this type of code:

```
public class FooCache {
    private static Map<Integer, Integer> sortOrderCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static Map<Integer, String> codeNameCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static void populateCache() {
        List<Foo> myThings = getThings();

        myThings.forEach(thing -> {
            sortOrderCache.put(thing.getId(), thing.getSortOrder());
            codeNameCache.put(thing.getId(), thing.getCodeName())
        });
    }
}
```

This is a trivialized example. I understand that this code violates Oracle's warning against stateful lamdas and side-effects. But I don't understand why this warning exists.

When running this code it appears to behave as expected. So how do I break this to demonstrate why it's a bad idea?

In sort, I read this:

> If executed in parallel, the non-thread-safety of ArrayList would
>   cause incorrect results, and adding needed synchronization would cause
>   contention, undermining the benefit of parallelism.

But can anyone add clarity to help me understand the warning?

Comment: Can you provide the warning?

Comment: I think he did.  What do you fail to understand about thread safety, immutable objects, and streams?

Comment: The quote is the warning I'm referring to. It's from the [java.util.stream API] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description)

Comment: There are no streams in your example.

Comment: @duffymo, I don't understand why they apply in this case. Is the Java Stream adding a thread in their implementation? Or is this code safe so long as I don't use it in concurrent code?

Comment: @shmosel The forEach is a terminal stream operation. Doesn't that mean it would apply to streams?

Comment: There is a terminal stream operation called `forEach()`, but you don't even have a stream. You're calling `List.forEach()`.

Comment: How can I have a stream operation without a stream? The collection.forEach() is just an allias for colletion.stream().forEach(), isn't it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: Anyway, the section you're quoting gives a pretty nice explanation already. If you want us to clarify something, you should specify what you found confusing.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "alias", but no. It's an unrelated method. In fact, it's declared by the `Iterable` interface, which doesn't even have a stream method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Javadoc:

> Note also that attempting to access mutable state from behavioral
>   parameters presents you with a bad choice with respect to safety and
>   performance; **if you do not synchronize access to that state, you have
>   a data race and therefore your code is broken, but if you do
>   synchronize access to that state, you risk having contention undermine
>   the parallelism you are seeking to benefit from**. The best approach is
>   to avoid stateful behavioral parameters to stream operations entirely;
>   there is usually a way to restructure the stream pipeline to avoid
>   statefulness.

The problem here is that if you access a mutable state, you loose on two side:

- Safety, because you need synchronization which the `Stream` tries to minimize
- Performance, because the required synchronization cost you (in your example, if you use a `ConcurrentHashMap`, this has a cost).

Now, in your example, there are several points here:

- If you want to use `Stream` and multi threading stream, you need to use `parralelStream()` as in `myThings.parralelStream()`; as it stands, the `forEach` method provided by `java.util.Collection` is simple `for each`.
- You use `HashMap` as a `static` member and you mutate it. `HashMap` is not threadsafe; you need to use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

In the lambda, and in the case of a `Stream`, you must not mutate the source of your stream:

```
myThings.stream().forEach(thing -> myThings.remove(thing));
```

This may work (but I suspect it will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`) but this will likely not work:

```
myThings.parallelStream().forEach(thing -> myThings.remove(thing));
```

That's because the `ArrayList` is not thread safe.

If you use a synchronized view (`Collections.synchronizedList`), then you would have a performance it because you synchronize on each access.

In your example, you would rather use:

```
sortOrderCache = myThings.stream()
                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                           Thing::getId, Thing::getSortOrder);
codeNameCache= myThings.stream()
                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                         Thing::getId, Thing::getCodeName);
```

The finisher (here the `groupingBy`) does the work you were doing and might be called sequentially (I mean, the Stream may be split across several thread, the the finisher may be invoked several times (in different thread) and then it might need to merge.

By the way, you might eventually drop the `codeNameCache`/`sortOrderCache` and simply store the id->Thing mapping.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the documentation is mentioning about the side effects demonstrated by the below code:

```
List<Integer> matched = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0 ; i< 10000 ; i++) {
    elements.add(i);
}

elements.parallelStream()
    .forEach(e -> {
        if(e >= 100) {
            matched.add(e);
        }
    });
System.out.println(matched.size());
```

This code streams through the list in parallel, and tries to add elements into other list if they match the certain criteria. As the resultant list is not synchronised, you will get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` while executing the above code.

The fix would be to create a new list and return, e.g.:

```
List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0 ; i< 10000 ; i++) {
    elements.add(i);
}   
List<Integer> matched = elements.parallelStream()
    .filter(e -> e >= 100)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(matched.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Side effects frequently makes assumptions about state and context. In parallel you are not guaranteed a specific order you see the elements in and multiple threads may run at the same time.

Unless you code for this this can give very subtle bugs which is very hard to track and fix when trying to go parallel.