# Filter values from a list based on priority

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of valid values for a type:

```
Set<String> validTypes = ImmutableSet.of("TypeA", "TypeB", "TypeC");
```

From a given list I want to extract the first value which has a valid type. In this scenario I would write something of this sort:

```
public class A{
    private String type;
    private String member;
}

List<A> classAList;
classAList.stream()
    .filter(a -> validTypes.contains(a.getType()))
    .findFirst();
```

However I would like to give preference to `TypeA`, i.e. if `classAList` has `TypeA` and `TypeB`, I want the object which has `typeA`. To do this one approach I've is:

```
Set<String> preferredValidTypes = ImmutableSet.of("TypeA");
classAList.stream()
    .filter(a -> preferredValidTypes.contains(a.getType()))
    .findFirst()
    .orElseGet(() -> {
        return classAList.stream()
        .filter(a -> validTypes.contains(a.getType()))
        .findFirst();
    }
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Think about it. If you want to prioritize in the presence of multiple possible matches you have to scan the entire list, until you get a match for the highest priority element.

Comment: I realize this should be an answer, but the answer is No. Your way is efficient, clean, simple, easy, just the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

filter list by type, order by type, collect to list, then just get first element

```
List<A> collect = classAList.stream()
                  .filter(a -> validTypes.contains(a.getType()))
                  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(A::getType))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(collect.get(0));
```

Comment: why `collect` only to get the first element? `sorted(...).findFirst`

Comment: you also assume that `TypeA` comes _before_ `TypeB` - and while true from the OP example, this might be over-simplified and not be what that OP _actually_ has

Comment: Also here the sorting is based on alphabetical order. I think explicitly mentioning the name would be safer since this won't work if I want typeB to be the preferred type

Comment: @user1692342 there is still the problem that you say you only care about `TypeA` as the priority, what about the rest? Suppose `TypeA` is not present - which one do you want to take? _whatever_? the ones in encounter order from the `Set`? or may be even some other order that you have in mind?

Comment: @user1692342 "sorting is based on alphabetical order" - I know of course, but the OP did not provide the real strings, anyway type comparison is another problem

Comment: @Eugene "Suppose TypeA is not present" - I think that it's solved by comparator, we'll just have next type with a lesser priority

Comment: @Adrian you could take into account that [sorting is stable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56036179/1059372) and do a solution around that

Comment: @Eugene … and `sorted(X).findFirst()` is an inefficient variant of `min(X)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom comparator like:

```
Comparator<A> comparator = (o1, o2) -> {
    if (preferredValidTypes.contains(o1.getType()) && !preferredValidTypes.contains(o2.getType())) {
        return 1;
    } else if (!preferredValidTypes.contains(o1.getType()) && preferredValidTypes.contains(o2.getType())) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

to sort the list and then `findFirst` from that list with your conditiion.

Comment: That won't work. If one contains "TypeA" and the other contains "TypeB" it will return 0 (equal elements) because preferredValidTypes contains both.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand Isn't that what is required, prioritizing the`preferredValidTypes` over others?

Comment: What I understood at least is that "TypeA" should have the priority over "TypeB" and so on.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand Note there are two different sets, i.e. `validTypes` and  `preferredValidTypes`... *I would like to give preference to TypeA, i.e. if classAList has TypeA and TypeB, I want the object which has typeA*

Comment: I might have misunderstood the problem then. If this is what he really wants, then your answer is good.

Answer (score 1):

i don't like the answers already given which use Comparator. Sorting is an expensive operation. You can do it with one walk through the list. Once you find a preferred value, you can break out, otherwise you continue to the end to find a valid.

In this case anyMatch can provide the possibility to break out from the stream processing:

```
MyVerifier verifier=new MyVerifier(validTypes,preferredValidTypes);
classAList.stream()
    .anyMatch(verifier);
System.out.println("Preferred found:"+verifier.preferred);
System.out.println("Valid found:"+verifier.valid);

public static class MyVerifier implements Predicate<A> {
    private Set<String> validTypes;
    private Set<String> preferredValidTypes;
    A preferred=null;
    A valid=null;

    public MyVerifier(Set<String> validTypes, Set<String> preferredValidTypes) {
        super();
        this.validTypes = validTypes;
        this.preferredValidTypes = preferredValidTypes;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(A a) {
        if(preferred==null && preferredValidTypes.contains(a.getType())) {
            preferred=a;
            // we can stop because we found the first preferred
            return true;
        } else if(valid==null && validTypes.contains(a.getType())) {
            valid=a;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Eric Duminil better ? :)

Answer (score 1):

One can, of course, define two lists, one with all valid types, and one with the preferred types.

However, here is another approach. Define *one* list, or actually, a `Map`, with the keys being the valid types, and the boolean values being whether the type is preferred.

```
Map<String, Boolean> validTypes = ImmutableMap.of(
    "TypeA", false,
    "TypeB", false,
    "TypeC", true
);
```

### Using `AtomicReference`

One option is the following:

```
AtomicReference<A> ref = new AtomicReference<>();
listOfAs.stream()
    .filter(t -> validTypes.containsKey(t.getType()))
    .anyMatch(t -> validTypes.get(ref.updateAndGet(u -> t).getType()));
```

`AtomicReference` now contains a preferred `A` if available, or another valid `A`, or if the stream is empty, then it contains `null`. This stream operation short-circuits if an `A` with a preferred type is found.

The **drawback of this option is that it creates side-effects**, [which is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041144/what-is-the-danger-of-side-effects-in-java-8-streams).

### Using `distinct()`

Another suggestion would be the following. It uses the same map structure, using a boolean to indicate which values are preferred. However, **it does not create side effects**.

```
Map<Boolean, A> map = listOfAs.stream()
    .filter(t -> validTypes.containsKey(t.getType()))
    .map(t -> new Carrier<>(validTypes.get(t.getType()), t))
    .distinct()
    .limit(2)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Carrier::getKey, Carrier::getValue));
```

It works as follows.

1. `filter` discards any element that is not a valid type.
2. Then, each element is mapped to a `Carrier<Boolean, A>` instance. A `Carrier` is a `Map.Entry<K, V>` which implements its `equals` and `hashCode` methods regarding only the `key`; the `value` does not matter. This is necessary for the following step,
3. `distinct()`, which discards any duplicate element. This way, only one preferred type and only one valid type is found.
4. We limit the stream to have 2 elements, one for each boolean. This is because the stream, which is lazy, stops evaluating after both booleans are found.
5. At last, we collect the Carrier elements into a Map.

The map contains now the following elements:

- `Boolean.TRUE` => `A` with a preferred type
- `Boolean.FALSE` => `A` with a valid type

Retrieve the appropriate element using

```
A a = map.getOrDefault(true, map.get(false)); // null if not found
```

Comment: Not that this was an approach, I’d recommend, but generally, instead of `.takeWhile(t -> !condition) .forEach(/* actually unintended operation */)`, you can use `.anyMatch(t -> condition)`…

Comment: @Holger You're right, updated. Well, I am curious about *why* you wouldn't recommend this approach. Is it about style? Performance?

Comment: Side effects in behavioral parameters, like predicates are discouraged in general. In this specific case, it’ll work, but may create a habit that backfires in other scenarios. And, well, resorting to `AtomicReference` does not add to performance due to unnecessary thread synchronization idioms. But the only other short-circuiting solution would be an ordinary loop…

Comment: @Holger Yes, I was looking for a way that would short-circuit if a preferred type was found. Many of the other answers either sort or materialize the complete resultset (at least the subset of valid types), and I was merely looking for a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to take care into account that sorting is *stable*, that is equal elements will appear in the same order as the initial source - and you need that to correctly get the *first* element from that `List<A>` that will satisfy your requirement, thus:

```
String priorityType = "TypeB";

Stream.of(new A("TypeA", "A"),
          new A("TypeB", "B"),
          new A("TypeC", "C"))
      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(A::getType, Comparator.comparing(priorityType::equals)).reversed())
      .filter(x -> validTypes.contains(priorityType))
      .findFirst()
      .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have preferred valid types in other collection so you can follow this code.

```
Map<String,A> groupByType = classAList
           .stream()
            /* additional filter to grouping by valid types.*/
          //.filter(a->validTypes.contains(a.getType())) 
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getType, Function.identity(),(v1, v2)->v1));
```

then use:

```
A result = preferredValidTypes
            .stream()
            .map(groupByType::get)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
```

or just group by preferred valid types

```
 A result2 = classAList
            .stream()
            .filter(a -> preferredValidTypes.contains(a.getType()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(A::getType, Function.identity(), (v1, v2) -> v1))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .findFirst()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Java8** you can use streams:

```
public static Carnet findByCodeIsIn(Collection<Carnet> listCarnet, String codeIsIn) {
    return listCarnet.stream().filter(carnet -> codeIsIn.equals(carnet.getCodeIsin())).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Additionally, in case you have many different objects (not only `Carnet`) or you want to find it by different properties (not only by `cideIsin`), you could build an utility class, to ecapsulate this logic in it:

```
public final class FindUtils {
    public static <T> T findByProperty(Collection<T> col, Predicate<T> filter) {
        return col.stream().filter(filter).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
}

public final class CarnetUtils {
    public static Carnet findByCodeTitre(Collection<Carnet> listCarnet, String codeTitre) {
        return FindUtils.findByProperty(listCarnet, carnet -> codeTitre.equals(carnet.getCodeTitre()));
    }

    public static Carnet findByNomTitre(Collection<Carnet> listCarnet, String nomTitre) {
        return FindUtils.findByProperty(listCarnet, carnet -> nomTitre.equals(carnet.getNomTitre()));
    }

    public static Carnet findByCodeIsIn(Collection<Carnet> listCarnet, String codeIsin) {
        return FindUtils.findByProperty(listCarnet, carnet -> codeIsin.equals(carnet.getCodeIsin()));
    }
}
```