# Remove repeated elements from the Lists inside Map

Tags: java, list, java-8, hashmap

Suppose I have the following map:

```
"A": [1, 2, 3, 4]
"B": [5, 6, 1, 7]
"C": [8, 1, 5, 9]
```

How do I remove the repeated elements from the arrays in order to return the map containing only the elements that were never repeated?

```
"A": [2, 3, 4]
"B": [6, 7]
"C": [8, 9]
```

Comment: Please, show what you've written to get closer to the solution.

Comment: Iterate over all values, regardless of under which key they belong, count amount of each of them (you can use Map for that). Now you know which character should be removed.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: It is not a homework. I need to create a method that will receive a HashMap like above and I need to remove itens in the lists that is repeated, and I can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you have to count the numbers in each list

```
Map<Integer, Long> countMap = map.values().stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

then filter where count == 1

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> result = map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream()
                    .filter(i -> countMap.get(i) == 1).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: @LucianoBorges this solution is slightly better because I'm using just one additional map and I'm doing just 2 iterations

Comment: Whereas the array inside the map is an array of object, should this identity function work? Because, in my case it's not working. Is it necessary  create the equals method on the object?

Comment: @LucianoBorges if that object is going to be map's key then yes, you need equals & hashCode. Or if your object have e.g. unique id you can replace identity function with e.g. `o -> o.getId()`

Answer (score 3):

You might want to do it this way:

```
// Initializing the map
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Integer>>() {
    {
        put("A", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)));
        put("B", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5, 6, 1, 7)));
        put("C", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(8, 1, 5, 9)));
    }
};

// finding the common elements
List<Integer> allElements = map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
Set<Integer> allDistinctElements = new HashSet<>();
Set<Integer> commonElements = new HashSet<>();
allElements.forEach(element -> {
    if(!allDistinctElements.add(element)) {
        commonElements.add(element);
    }
});

// removing the common elements
map.forEach((key, list) -> list.removeAll(commonElements));

// printing the map
map.forEach((key, list) -> System.out.println(key + " = " + list));
```

**Output:**

```
A = [2, 3, 4]
B = [6, 7]
C = [8, 9]
```

Comment: The number 5 should be removed too.

Comment: @LucianoBorges Oops I thought you wanted to remove elements common in all the lists. Now I have updated the code. Please check.

Comment: it's a bad idea to use `forEach` with side effects - read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041144/what-is-the-danger-of-side-effects-in-java-8-streams)

Comment: @Adrian I think it is related to accessing the `static Map` that is shared when it is being used in multiple threads (parallelism) like in `parallelStream`. I don't think there will be any such issue here in my code.