# Java 8 Streams - filter by a property of an object

Tags: java, java-stream

I've got an Object called `Price`, that describes the selling and buying behaviour of an item. Next to some other properties it looks mainly like this:

```java
public class Price {
    private PriceType type;
    private int amount;
    private ItemData itemData;
    
    //...
}
```

with respective getters and setters. `amount` is the amount of this item that shall be sold/bought, and ItemData describes the specifications of the item. PriceType is an Enum, that's either `PriceType.SELLING` or `PriceType.BUYING`.

I now have a method, which job it is, to find the best matching Price in a list. All my Prices are stored in a list simply called `pricesList`. Until now, my method just went through the list, and returned the first `Price` that matched the `PriceType` and the `ItemData`:

```java
public static Price getPriceByBiggestBaseAmountMatchingGivenAmount(
                        ItemData dataOfCollected, PriceType priceType, int amount) {
    return pricesList
        .stream()
        .filter(p -> 
            p.getItemData().equals(dataOfCollected) &&
            p.getType().equals(priceType))
        .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

However this completely ignores the fact that there is a minimal amount that must be respected. So, what I need is that it does not just find me the first `Price` that somehow matches the `ItemData` and the `PriceType`, but it should also take account the minimal amount. It should ignore every `Price` that has an amount smaller than the given amount, and of all the remaining ones, it should return the one with the biggest `price.getAmount()`. This might be a bit hard to understand so here's an example:

Say I have three Price-Objects of the same PriceType and ItemData, so they all describe, lets say a `PriceType.BUYING` price - ergo the price my program will pay for a given amount of this item.

```
price1.getAmount() == 1 //So this is describing the price for a single item.
price2.getAmount() == 6 //So this is describing the price for half a dozen of the item.
price3.getAmount() == 64 //Describing the price for an entire stack of the item.
```

If I do `getPriceByBiggestBaseAmountMatchingGivenAmount(data, type, x)` for some `x`es this shall be returned:

```
x: 1 => price1
x: 3 => price1
x: 7 => price2
x: 63 => price2
x: 64 => price3
x: 120 => price3
x: -1 => null
```

I have no idea how to achieve that with a stream, of course I could do it with a for loop, but that's something I'd only do as a last resort...

Comment: Well, a for-loop would still be a good thing to use. Using a stream you'd probably want to do2 things: 1) filter for amount >= required amount (remove those with a lower amount) and 2) sort by ascending amount and then take the first match

Comment: Why don't we set the minimal amount condition in `.filter()` itself and then sort the data based on amount in desc order before `.findFirst()` ?

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan intermediate actions in `Stream`s should not have any side effects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041144/what-is-the-danger-of-side-effects-in-java-8-streams

Comment: I see... So parallelStream is the answer along with the filter and sort method that me and Thomas were talking about?? The same that Rahel has answered expect for the unsafe stream() ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with good ol' for loops, especially if you don't understand streams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it this way:
First filtering out all prices that are smaller than the desired amount and then taking the biggest value out of the list with max().

```
public static Price getPriceByBiggestBaseAmountMatchingGivenAmount(
                    ItemData dataOfCollected, PriceType priceType, int amount) {
return pricesList
    .stream()
    .filter(p -> 
        p.getItemData().equals(dataOfCollected) &&
        p.getType().equals(priceType) &&
        p.getAmount() <= amount)  // remove bigger amounts
    .max(Comparator.comparing(Price::getAmount)) // take the biggest
    .orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much for the quick reply <3. I already thought about something like that, but I somehow missed that this Comparator-stuff could solve my problem this easily during my research x)

Comment: I just switched the >= to a <=, please make sure it is how you need it. The example confused me a bit